# How can convert Mirror To Orginal class or struct using swift language

Tags: swift, swift4.2

i have an question about the Mirror reflection .
i convert my struct to mirror to iterate through all the properties to get values and after i iterate through it and change the values in properties i need to convert mirror again to the original struct with values which i edited but i can't , is swift language have way to do this conversion ?

the code below

```
//MARK:- loop get tags
    func getTags(filter: Any){

        let getTags = Mirror(reflecting: filter)
        for (tag) in getTags.children {

            if let getTag = tag.value as? String {
                if let _ = Int(getTag) {

                }else {
                    if getTag != "" && getTag != "All" {
                        arrayOfTags.append(getTag)
                    }
                }
            }// if let
        }// end for loop

    }
```

thanks

Comment: For what exactly do you need this? Using `Mirror` is expensive and since Swift is type-safe language, you should know which types you’re using

Comment: i have a custom struct and i using the reflection to get the properties and iterate through all.to do something in values after that edited i need convert it back to the custom struct and send it by notification center

Comment: Why don't you just use your `struct`? If you know exactly what type you are working with, there is no point to use `Mirror`.

Comment: as i told you i need access to all properties in my custom struct by looping and it's have many properties. i can't use struct because must i iterate through all properties and edited values depend on some conditions so i am using the mirror

Comment: Did u manage to get a neat solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't construct a struct without hardcore memory manipulation. You could create objets with functions that are still available from Objective C. You could set the property with the setValue forKey function. Your objects needs to be derived from NSObject.

Doing this and taking into account all scenario's is quite a challenge. There is a CocoaPod library that could help with this. Have a look at [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) You could create a dictionary from your object and an object from your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

it's been asked a while a go.. but just in case I think you may be looking for https://cocoapods.org/pods/EVReflection